# Load file bundled within jar only if run as a jar

Tags: java, configuration-files

I have a properties file that I've included within a jar I'll be distributing. Before I decided to include the file within the jar I was loading it like

```
properties.load(new FileInputStream(configFileName));
```

But this stopped working once the file was placed inside the jar so I changed the code to

```
properties.load(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(configFileName));
```

Only problem is I have unit tests that use my properties (which are loaded statically so I can't mock it). The unit tests are run before the jar is made so they all fail now. Is there an elegant way to handle a file that will be in a jar only if the program is run as a jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem probably is that this file is not visible to your classloader..

i'd use this

```
Classloader cl = getClass().getClassloader();
properties.load(cl.getResourceAsStream(configFileName))
```

pay attention to your classload if this app is a webapplication.. you'll have many classloaders on this case.. your resource must be visible to this classloader.. 
in a servlet container like tomcat they work this way

```
  Bootstrap
      |
   System
      |
   Common
    /     \
Webapp1   Webapp2 ...
```

you can read more here 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is call `getResourceAsStream()`, and if it returns null call `new FileInputStream()`.

But a better question is: why aren't the properties in your classpath when you run unit tests? If you're using a build tool like Maven, then this should be automatic. And it would give a better sense that you're actually building what you think you are.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you explain what you mean by putting the properties in classpath I'm new to java development. I am using a build tool, but it's proprietary and not Maven.

Comment: If you're using a proprietary build tool, then I don't know how you'd do this, other than putting your properties file in the same directory as your code. And even that may not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you happy to have the properties file live with your source code then try:

```
properties.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("my.properties"));
```

The `my.properties` file will have to live in the same package as the `.java` file in this case.